# Статистика сайта: "посетителей в день" -- что стоит за этой цифрой?

Tags: поддержка, статистика

Речь идет о статистике на главной странице ru.SO.

К сожалению я не разбираюсь во многих деталях web, поэтому краткие объяснения принципов сбора такой статистики, наряду с релевантными деталями приветствуются.

Как конкретно вычисляется, что за день нас посетило 40402 человека?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Обычно под "посетителями в день" подразумеваются "уники" — уникальные посетители. При заходе на сайт обычно пользователю задаётся уникальный идентификатор (независимо от наличия регистрации), который сохраняется в печенье. Если посетеитель проходится по нескольким страницам, он всё равно считается одним посетителем.

Если вкратце, это число — что-то в духе `SELECT DISTINCT(UserId) FROM Visits WHERE VisitDateTime BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo`.

Answer (score 3):

Версия основателя SO (из прошлого): *"sum of all unique IP address question views"* -- то есть общее кол-во просмотров вопросов, где [просмотры с каждого ip/учётной записи считаются один раз [в течение 15 минут] для каждого вопроса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/137096).

Ещё видел версию на Мете, что это усредненное за последние две недели значение.

Достаточно неочевидно что это называют visits/day.

В общем случае, сайты, которые считают трафик могут показывать кол-во просмотров страниц, упомянутые уникальные сессии (кол-во cookies полученных/отправленных  quantcast), и оценивать количество людей даже если с разных устройств заходить (с телефона, планшета, ноута, настольного компьютера дома и на работе).